# How to composite using-by objects (real world example)

Tags: oop, design-patterns, architecture, composite

Hey i have question with a real word example.
Its related to my two other, but not really answered questions here:

https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/423392/no-trivial-god-class-refactoring

and

https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/425113/different-composition-techniques-from-the-perspective-of-the-client

Let's say we have a switch with the methods `switchOn()`, `switchOff()`.
The switch(es) are included in some other structure, for example a `switch-bag`, from where i can pull out the switches.
This can be seen as a ready system.

Now i want to introduce the possibility of switching these switches on after a certain time automatically: A `time switch`

The `time switch` ueses now the `"normal" switch`.
The `normal switch` doesn't have to know something about the `time switch`.

So but now the client can pull out the `normal switc`h from the `switch-bag` and now he want also to get to the `time-switch` related to these `normal switch`, maybe to configure a new time.

**And this is my question, how can the client get to the `time-switch`?**

**There are a few possibilites:**

- I refactor the `normal switch` class to a third-class where the
  `normal-switch` and the `time switch` lives bundled in it. But for this,
  i break some other client code which still uses the `normal switch`, but
  get now from the switch bag a "Combinator"-Class/Object out of it.
- I don't change anything of the `normal switch` class. The client if he
  wants to get access to the `time switch` have to ask a Map which `time switch` is related to it. (I think this approach is classical a
  relation-programming style like a sql relationship database and its
  not anymore real object-oriented style)
- I extend the `normal switch`: Here i also have different options:

  - I change it to a big facade, which delegates the calls to the
    `normal-switch` and `time switch` (its similar to my first solution with
    the combinator, but here with an facade don't breaking some existing
    client code)
  - i extend the `normal switch` letting the existing `normal switch` code
    untouched and introduce a component holder. Into this component
    holder i inject the `time switch`. So i have these methods there:
    `switchOn();` `switchOff();` `getComponent("timeSwitch")`. But these
    approach feels like a entity-component system
    (https://medium.com/ingeniouslysimple/entities-components-and-systems-89c31464240d)
    but is that still object oriented programming?

i think the last solution is the best one, because its the most flexible.

But what do you think which approach is the best, maybe some approach i didnt mentionend here?

**Edit:**
One more thing you must to know here: The `time switch` is one extension of the `normal switch`. One of many. So i want to add of course different more things XYZ switches/behavior extensions to the `normal switch`

Comment: This guy would say to avoid using inheritance (extending) because you can't predict the future of what you want to do with your switch. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wfMtDGfHWpA That said, I don't think your question will have an answer because it is not focused enough, and there is no code.

Comment: Keep things as simple as possible.

Comment: @Fuhrmanator its not about inheritance (yeah the word extend in my question could be misleading; but its more meant like i extend it by i put more code into it^^, for example i add some kind of list to the normal switch, in that i can save the time-switches as related compontents (entity-component......), so that i can get later the time-switch from a normal switch easily and without breaking current client-code)

Answer (score 0):

**Update**: answer totally re-written (so the first comment won't make sense any more).

To summarize:

- SwitchBag provides access to a list/collection of switches.
- Switches have methods like on() and off().
- You want to extend the behavior of at least some switches can do stuff themselves based on the passing of time, etc.
- Clients (e.g. the UI) need access to the switches classes.

You make comments like

> and now he want also to get to the time-switch related to these normal
> switch

which suggests you have one of each, etc - which is way more complex than it needs to be.  Here's some options to consider - some of your ones were heading in the right direction.

**Option A: One type of switch**

This assumes that the solutions design & functional drivers don't push you to create huge and overly complex switches.  For example, let's say some of your switches need to do something after a period of time, others don't.  Such a difference is not necessarily reason enough to make a separate class.

E.g. you can implement a time related property like `Duration`, if `Duration` > 0 then time logic applies and gets executed; < 0 means no time logic is applied (normal switch behavior).

I'm assuming here that any client can get access to any switch via the SwitchBag.

This is the option I would start with because it's simple and still allows plenty of functional scope.

**Option B: Smart SwitchBag, Dumb Swithes**

I'm not sure if I like the smell of this option because it tightly-couples the SwitchBag and Switch classes, but it could be useful.

- Keep the switch class as dumb as possible.
- SwitchBag knows about switches, it controls access to them (and their properties/methods).  Use class structure and access modifiers to control this.
- SwitchBag can decide to do stuff to switches based on time if it wants to.

In this approach, switches will be mostly properties, and be a little bit like the SwitchBags personal database, only it's fluid based on objects at runtime.

Note - you can still have events on the switches.

**Option C: Interfaces**

Create a basic switch.  Create interfaces that are designed to be applied to switch class(es), that extend them as necessary.  E.g.:

```
interface ITimeBehaviour{
  double InitialDuration
  double TimeUntilChange
}
```

At runtime you can see if a given switch instance implements the interface and respond accordingly.  But whilst you **can** do this I'm not sure **why** you would, based on what I understand of your problem.

**Other Thoughts**

- Your comments suggest you've thought a lot about OO concepts like inheritance and methods, but I saw no evidence you've considered **asynchronous** programming techniques - such as using **events**.  If you know nothing about this then do some research and get up to speed, then see if that offers an elegant solution to your problem.
- **Design Patterns** - are you familiar with the idea of design patterns? If you aren't, be sure to research that too.  There's heaps of good content online, which describe patterns that might already solve the fundamentals of your problem.

Comment: yeah thats right, what you wrote -> we come from a normal switch which does not have to know something about their related time-switch; so i in that case i must iterate through all time-switches or better i have a map, where the relation is saved, but that feels more like a relational-data-mapping and not so object-oriented like